# OMNIUpdate Data Entry Automations

Tags: automation

I work with OmniUpdate content management system to enter data for my office. Is there anyway to automate data entry on Omni Update? Like is there any way I could create an excel sheet of redundant data and integrate that data into the Omni Update multi edit templates?

Answer (score 0):

Good question! No method is available at the moment out-of-the-box from OU Campus. I suppose you could convert your spreadsheet to CSV, write a script to take your CSV data and convert it to a series of XML files that follow the MultiEdit format in OU Campus. The only other option I can think of is using the API in OU Campus to read the data and transform it, but the first approach, if feasible for you, would be the only real option that I see here.